# Draw a view with image pattern

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to render the view with images pattern as a picture below. At first, I push a needed amount of items in an array and then I called the method that returned me a view(row).

```
getRow = () => {
        return(
            <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
                { this.images.map(function(img,i) { return img; }) }
            </View>
        )
    }
```

How I can imagine, I need a two-dimensional array. I know how many rows I need. So, I have made this:

```
prepareTable = () => {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < pattern.height.count; ++i) {
        arr.push((this.drawRow()))
    }
    return arr
}
```

And when I want to render them :

```
render() {

   let arr = prepareTable()
   return(
   <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:'column', justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
       {arr.map((row,i)=>{return row})}
    </View>
   )
}
```

But it doesn't work. Where is my mistake

[image]

Comment: what is inside `this.images`? also what does `this. drawRow ` do?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy and best way is just use a single View with flexWrap, store your all images in an array call the map function inside your View with flexWrap.

```
render(){
   return(
          <View style={styles.gridView}>
                    {imagesArray.map((image, index) => this.renderImage(image, index))}
          </View>);
}
renderImage=(image, index)=>{
    return (
            <Image .../>[![Hope it will help , you can show your images like this way.][1]][1]
        );
}

const styles = {
    gridView: {
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of unknowns right now:

- what is inside `this.images` ?
- what does `this.drawRow` do ?

So in this answer, there are a couple assumptions:

- `this.images` is an array of Image components with N elements like:

  ```
  [
   (<Image
      style={styles.image}
      source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
   />),
   (...)
  ]
  ```

---

If we abstract the logic a little bit we would have something like the following:

```
    // `this.images` seems to be a little sturdy for now so instead we will
    // have an `imagesPerRow` method that takes in the number of
    // images that we want on each `row`
    imagesPerRow(number) {
      const img = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
       img.push(
          <Image
            style={styles.image}
            source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
          />
        );
      }
      return img;
    }
    // the `getRow` method wrap the array of images inside a `View` element
    // Here number will be the number of images inside it
    getRow = (number) => {
      return (
      <View style={styles.row}>
        { this.imagesPerRow(number) }
      </View>
      );
    }

    // drawTable takes two parameters rowNum (amount of rows)and
    // columnNum (amount of columns), these will render the actual table
    drawTable(rowNum, columnNum) {
      const rows = []
      for(let i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
       rows.push(this.getRow(columnNum));
      }
      return rows;
    }

    // In the render method we just call the `drawTable` with the desired params
    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          { this.drawTable(10, 4) }
        </View>
      );
    }
```

It is important to keep styling in mind, otherwise it will look all cramped

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        backgroundColor: '#222222',
      },
      image: {
        width: 50,
        height: 50

      },
      row: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }
    });
```

here you can find a [working example](https://repl.it/JjZp/3) that I created.

Hope this helps.